# htaccess sequential redirection

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm new with the htaccess redirection, and I'm having some trouble with how it works, I think that is because I need something a little bit different.

I want this

```
http://localhost/webroot/type_enduro-cross-trial/brand_yamaha/
```

to be redirected to

```
http://localhost/webroot/search.php?type=enduro-cross&trial=brand_yamaha
```

I use that values as filters from products; but the original URL is generated in two steps.

Example:

The user goes to the main page (`http://localhost/webroot`), and wants to filter by type, so when he clicks, the filter is applied and the URL changes to `http://localhost/webroot/type_enduro-cross-trial` and it works!

But I want the user to be able to add more filters, so now he wants to filter by some brand, and when he click the URL changes to `http://localhost/webroot/type_enduro-cross-trial/brand_yamaha/`. And so on with more filters.

This rewrite rule works to obtain the value of the first parameter:

`RewriteRule ^([^_/]+)_([^_/]+)/([^_/]*) search.php?$1=$2 [L]`

But when I add more filters, it clearly ignore them, and I have no idea of how must the rewrite rule should be.

Thanks, and sorry for my English!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is non-trivial to do with `.htaccess`. Instead of solving this complicated within `.htaccess` just only leave a single rule inside the file and do the work inside your `search.php` script. This allows you a greater flexibility.

Just pass everything as a single parameter to the php script, like:

```
RewriteRule /pages/(.+) /page.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

In your php script you do some string processing on `$_GET['page']` (exemplary from the example RewriteRule above), e.g. by using [`explode`](http://php.net/explode).

Inside PHP you can far better work with arrays, something you can not at all inside the `.htaccess` file.

> *Examples have been taken from the original* [Apache HTTP Mod_Rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).